# OpenSSL extension not working on PHP v7 & IIS 10

Tags: php, iis, https, openssl

I have scowered all over the internet and I can't get Open SSL extension working with PHP running on IIS. I have tried uncommenting "extension=php_openssl.dll" on the INI file like everyone is suggesting and also followed the below tutorial too which is using PHP manager for IIS but, no luck. I have tried disabling/re-enabling Openssl extension and also tried restarting IIS. I also double checked the ext folder and the php_openssl.dll file is present there.
Every time I try to process HTTPS URLs I get this error message "Warning: file_get_contents(): Unable to find the wrapper "https" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? in...".

OpenSSL configuration tutorial: https://www.phpkb.com/kb/article/configuring-php-openssl-extension-with-iis-via-php-manager-on-windows-181.html

Thanks for reading my question.

Comment: Can you confirm that the `extension_dir = "ext"` is also uncommented?

Comment: Yes, it is also uncommented and set as extension_dir="C:\Program Files\PHP\v7.0\ext\"

Comment: Did you add this one `allow_url_include = On` follow the `extension=php_openssl.dll`?

Comment: Yes, allow_url_include is also set to on and doesn't make any difference

Comment: How did you configure PHP and open SSL on IIS and what's the detailed version of PHP 7? If you can provide more detailed information, that may help me reproduce the issue.

Comment: PHP was set up by our hosting provider most likely using Web platform installer. All the other extensions simply work after uncommenting "extension=...". The PHP version is 7.0.9 and the corresponding DLL file for OpenSSL is present on the ext folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who might come across this issue. I got it working by re-installing PHP from scratch using this manual CMD installation method on the tutorial below. After installation, I uncommented the line "extension=openssl....." in the INI file & it worked as intended again.

PHP CMD manual installation tutorial:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.windows.manual.php

I chose the non-threaded version of PHP for IIS as, it was the recommended config. by the Microsoft documentation.